# Heatmap SAS some labels bold

Tags: sas, label, heatmap

I'm trying to perform a heatmap on SAS with some bold labels on the y axis. I didn't find the option in the sgplot heatmap to do that. I've tryied to use the dattrmap option and create subgroup but none of the test I maid work.

My code is the following:

```
PROC SGPLOT DATA=mydata NOBORDER NOAUTOLEGEND dattrmap=attrheatmap;
HEATMAP X=response Y=item /colorresponse=percent discretex discretey colormodel=(white blue);
text X=response Y=item text=percent/TEXTATTRS=(color=black family="Arial") ;
YAXIS DISPLAY=(nolabel) VALUEATTRS=(Family=Arial) REVERSE;
XAXIS DISPLAY=(nolabel) VALUEATTRS=(Family=Arial);
gradlegend;RUN;
```

I added the dattrmap option and specified my table with the following data:

```
id   textcolor textweight value
text   Black       bold       1
text   Black      normal      2
```

Then, in the Mydata data set, I specified 1 or 2 according to the label I needed to have them in bold, in a column called "subgroup". I've tried the following test:

```
text X=response Y=item text=percent/TEXTATTRS=(color=black family="Arial") textgroup=subgroup textgroupid=text;
```

and

```
HEATMAP X=response Y=item /colorresponse=percent discretex discretey colormodel=(white blue) textgroup=subgroup;
```

Is anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use an attribute map on an axis directly.

Your best bet is either to use annotation, or to make an axis *table*, which does support this.

See [Sanjay's blog post](https://blogs.sas.com/content/graphicallyspeaking/2017/10/22/tips-tricks-segmented-discrete-axis/) on the topic, or my example below:

```
data mydata;
 set sashelp.class;
 response=weight;
 item=age;
 percent = weight;
 groupid = ifn(age>13,1,2);
run;
data attrheatmap;

  input id $ textcolor $ textweight $ value;
  datalines;
 text red bold 1
 text Black normal 2
 ;;;;
 run;

PROC SGPLOT DATA=mydata NOBORDER NOAUTOLEGEND dattrmap=attrheatmap;
HEATMAP X=response Y=item /colorresponse=percent discretex discretey colormodel=(white blue);
text X=response Y=item text=percent/TEXTATTRS=(color=black family="Arial") ;
YAXIS DISPLAY=(novalues nolabel) VALUEATTRS=(Family=Arial) REVERSE;
YAXISTABLE item/position=left location=outside textgroup=groupid textgroupid=text stat=mean;
XAXIS DISPLAY=(nolabel) VALUEATTRS=(Family=Arial);
gradlegend;RUN;
```

Comment: Thanks @Joe, it works perfectly! I saw that yaxistable option could help on my problem but I didn't understood how, thanks!